# How to read data on Raspberry Pi with Python from HID device?

Tags: python, usb, hid

I am new at Raspberry and Python, so I will be very glad if you help me at my problem. I need to read some data from weight scale when button on scale is pressed. When I connected this scale via USB on PC, I saw that it works as HID. When I pressed the button, data were written in some text document for example. So, now I am going to connect this scale on Raspberry Pi to read and manipulate with data. Can you give me some example, advice, which library I need to import? I want to write a script, that waits for incomming data and then something do with it. Thanks for help.